# How to get the value with max number of items in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with this columns:

`id | param | value | flag | date_v (datetime field)`

And I need to get average value gruping by param, flag and date(every 15 minutes), and I get this with:

```
select param, flag, avg(value) 
        date_add(date_add(date(date_v), interval date_format(date_v, '%H') hour), interval ceil(date_format(date_v, '%i')/15)*15 minute) as date_v,
        count(*) as items
from instant_values
group by param, flag, 
        date_add(date_add(date(date_v), interval date_format(date_v, '%H') hour), interval ceil(date_format(date_v, '%i')/15)*15 minute)
```

With this query I get every average value from each flag, but, I need to get only the average value from the most repeated flag of each grouped date_v.

Thank you.

Edit

With my query I get somethin like this:

```
"19"    "T" "63,00"  "2016-01-07 08:00:00"  "1"
"19"    "T" "158,94" "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "2"
"19"    "M" "178,00" "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "1"
"20"    "T" "1,89"   "2016-01-07 08:00:00"  "1"
"20"    "M" "8,00"   "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "2"
"20"    "F" "1,10"   "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "3"
```

And I need to get only the rows that ends with the max number for every param and "hour", in this case, I need to get this:

```
"19"    "T" "63,00"  "2016-01-07 08:00:00"  "1"
"19"    "T" "158,94" "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "2"
"20"    "T" "1,89"   "2016-01-07 08:00:00"  "1"
"20"    "F" "1,10"   "2016-01-07 08:15:00"  "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get one value, you can use variables.  I think you just want one value per "date".  Here is an example:

```
select pfd.*
from (select pfd.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = date_v, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := date_v, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select param, flag, avg(value) 
                   date_add(date_add(date(date_v), interval date_format(date_v, '%H') hour), interval ceil(date_format(date_v, '%i')/15)*15 minute) as date_v,
                   count(*) as items
            from instant_values
            group by param, flag, 
                     date_add(date_add(date(date_v), interval date_format(date_v, '%H') hour), interval ceil(date_format(date_v, '%i')/15)*15 minute)
           ) pfd cross join
           (select @d := '', @rn := 0)
      order by date_v, count(*) desc
     ) pfd
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I have added more information to clarify what I want to do. I try with your code but I only get one result.

Comment: @Darkerviti . . . This should be returning one result per `date_v`.

Comment: I'm getting a warning : Incorrect datetime value: "for column 'date_v' at row 1.
It gives me this error when I comment the where clause, because there is no column seqnum.

Comment: @Darkerviti . . . That is curious.  The subquery is the same as your subquery, so it should work the same way.